# How to rearrange a tikzpicture in a page that uses the class suftesi

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I drew an ER schema for a database and put it in my mini-thesis written using `suftesi`. This class has the peculiarity of adding a mini-column beside the main column of contents, used for notes. This results in my `tikzpicture` (coded using `tikz-er2` by Pàvel Calado) not being centered in the page. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I added a screenshot to better show this problem:

[image]

EDIT: This is the source .tex file and the tikz-er2.sty file bundle. [puu.sh/1Jq1m](http://puu.sh/1Jq1m)

Comment: @unNaturhal You need to add a minimal working example in the question (not a link to a bunch of files). If you don't know what a MWE is, have a look at [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/14) explanation. In summary, we need to see a complete document illustrating your problem, starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It should contain all the packages necessary to compile your code, but no unnecessary packages so the problem is isolated.

Comment: It may seem like too much to ask, but you will notice that if you do that you will get help much faster since it will be easier for those reading your question to see what the problem is and adjust your code (without having to create one of their own).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `current page` node and its center, furthermore you could let TikZ do the scaling instead of using `\scalebox`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,scale=0.75,transform shape]
  \node at (current page.center) {
      % your picture follows
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: centered TikZ picture]